# Access 2007 Forecasting Date range

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm looking for some help / guidance on implementing some kind of forecasting form in my access database. What i'd like to achieve is for the user to pick out a project from a drop down list (which i have) and then select a from & to date from two date pickers. When the dates are selected - e.g Jan 2016 - Jan 2017, the database creates 12 blank entries where the user can input various amounts in each cell.

The database has the set up where a single project can have multiple calendar dates. I've tried using a cross tab query in the first instance however, as I quickly found out, it's non-updateable. I've looked into using a 'temp' table and then possibly using an update function from the temp table and inserting new records however, I'm really hoping there is a simpler way.. Has any one encountered a similar issue / any advice on the best approach?

Update:
Table structure of the temp table (if this is the best way?) would look something like:

Ideally, if the user selects the range Jan 15 - Jan 16, then the database 'fills in' the remaining months. In the db the table would then look like:

`[Project Id] [Month] [Year]`
`[1]            [1]    [2015]`
`[1]            [2]    [2015]`
`[1]            [3]    [2015]`
etc..

I'm unsure how to implement this; i.e on selection of starting and end months, create the entries in between.

Comment: This question might be a bit too broad to get decent answers. Also, if you're looking to implement a form, have you tried anything with a form yet? You say you want the form to create blank entries in your database and then say that the database is set up where a single project can have multiple calendar dates - perhaps supply some dummy data so we can see the structure of this data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I can see why it's maybe come across as a bit too broad. I've updated the question to include specific issue

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I've supplied an answer that might give some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may differ from your set up, but I'd create a table to store all your forecast data permanently.. e.g. in this illustration I've created **tblForecast** with these fields:

[image]

I've then created a form with a combo box to select the Project, 2 text boxes to provide the From and To dates and then a command button to run some VBA that will create the records as you've described. Below these controls is a subform that uses **tblForecast** as its `RecordSource`; this will be used to display the records that the form will create and allow users to put their own data against fields *ForecastData1* and *ForecastData2*:

[image]

Here's the annotated VBA code on the click event on that command button:

```vb
Private Sub cmdCreate_Click()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim newRecs As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Open tblForecast so we can add new records to it
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblForecast")

    ' Find out how many records we need to add based on the number of months between
    ' the From and To dates supplied on the form
    newRecs = DateDiff("m", Me.txtFromDate, Me.txtToDate)

    ' Initialise our counter for the loop
    i = 1

    ' Start a loop that will create a new record for each of the months needed
    Do While i <= newRecs

        With rs

            .AddNew

            ' Pre-poulate the ProjectID, ForecastMonth and ForecastYear fields with
            ' the relevant data
            !ProjectID = Me.cboProject
            !ForecastMonth = Month(DateAdd("m", i - 1, Me.txtFromDate))
            !ForecastYear = Year(DateAdd("m", i - 1, Me.txtFromDate))               

            .Update

            ' Increment the counter before next loop iteration
            i = i + 1

        End With

    Loop

    ' Requery subform to see the new records that have been added
    Me.tblForecast_sub.Form.Requery

    ' Tidy-up memory
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

So, if you provide a Project and From and To dates...

[image]

...and then click the command button:

[image]

The VBA code creates a record for each month between the From and To dates supplied and pre-populates the *ProjectID*, *ForecastMonth* and *ForecastYear* fields with appropriate data. It's then up to the user to complete the remaining *ForecastData1* and *ForecastData2* fields.

[Here's a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZia0JTdTBYS0pYSFU/view?usp=sharing) to the Access mock-up file so you can have a closer look if you like.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!
I'll try this out this morning & let you know how I get on. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what was needed. Thank you for providing comments for the VBA as well, really appreciated it

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As we must assume the forecast should be persisted, the first choice in Access will be to use a table to hold the forecast data. I can't see what "simpler way" there could be.